# Handling image onload function for multiple images

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload

```
function handleonload(url , callback)
{ 
var img = new Image();


  img.onError = function() {
    alert('Cannot load image: "'+url+'"');
  };
  img.crossOrigin = '';
  img.onload = function() {
    callback(img);
  };


  img.src = url;
}
handleonload(imageurl,callbackfunction);
```

I am using this function for multiple images ? But i am not getting a   correctly map output images some of them are repeated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `imagesLoaded`: http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/

Usage is straightforward: `imagesLoaded( elem, callback );`

Comment: would you give me a fiddle

Comment: Can i directly enter a url instead of document.querySelector("#images") as i am having url

Comment: It'd be simple to create an `Image` object and pass it to `imagesLoaded` with any URL you like.